# What is happening to this lambda ? could someone explain

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc-object

```
proc_obj = -> proto { print proto; puts("World")}

puts proc_obj["Hi"]

puts proc_obj.call("Hello") #Is this is the same as above
```

please refer me to some link to demystify this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening to that lambda is that you're calling its `[]` method, which causes the lambda to be executed with the argument `"Hi"`. And yes, calling `call` is the same as calling `[]`.

Comment: How can i pass multiple arguments to lambda ? say proc.call("hello","konichiwa")

Comment: @pankajdoharey Yes, like that.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html#method-i-5B-5D